# MySQL Load File Invalid Integer

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv

I am trying to import the following CSV data into a fresh clean table with the below settings. And keep getting two entries added and then warnings. Why is it giving an error? I have changed it from Inno to MyISAM as I thought that might be the issue, but no luck.

```
16,"Data point 1"
15,"Data point 2"
14,"Point 3a"
13,"Data total"
```

After running this SQL

> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Me/CSV.csv'
>        INTO TABLE points
>        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
>        LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'

I get the following warning

> 2 row(s) affected, 2 warning(s): 1366 Incorrect integer value: ' 15'
>   for column 'id' at row 2

The table is setup as follows.

```
id INT(11) Default 0 PK
value VARCHAR(45) Default NULL
```

Comment: Maybe your lines are not actually terminated by \r, but \r\n instead? That would explain the whitespace character in _Incorrect integer value: ' 15'_ – it would just be the \n. So try `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` instead.

Comment: Put that as an answer and I will accept it as that simple error I missed was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your lines are not actually terminated by \r, but \r\n instead? That would explain the whitespace character in *Incorrect integer value: ' 15'* – it would just be the \n.

So try `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that your lines are not actually terminated by just '\r' but '\r\n'.

If this is the case, you will most likely get the errors you are describing

Perhaps try something like:

```
load data local infile '<path2csv>' into table test.test_table fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\r\n'
```

I would also check the actual text file with an editor which has the option to show hidden characters, such as Vi (I believe you can get a graphical version of Vim for windows).